# Exporting data to text with Findstr command

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have this batch file that displays the lines where "mb" is found:

```
findstr "mb" file.txt
```

I'm intersted in exporting this data to a text file. I tried this batch:

```
findstr "mb" file.txt > new.txt
```

Instead of exporting the lines with "mb" it exports a file equal to the input.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not see any errors and redirection should work. Can you share the full content of script?

Comment: Show us the expected and the actual result.

Comment: Apparently, lines that the CMD and Notepad++ consider separated, the output txt file considers as one. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: Your file maybe came from a Linux system which separates lines just with a linefeed instead of the CarriageReturn+Linefeed that Windows needs. You probably need to run the file through `unix2dos`.